# Comparing similarity of two words given by user as a web application in flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

Flask beginner here. Trying to make a simple web application that allows user to compare two inputs and outputting percentage of similarity.

For example:

Input 1: ABBCD
Input 2: Gallant Duck
Letter A, C, and D exists in both input. Thus the percentage is 60% (3 similar characters divided by 5 characters of Input 1, case insensitive).

Function for this could be easily written in Python as follows:

```
import math

def compare_word_percentage(str1, str2):
        s1 = str1.casefold()
        s2 = str2.casefold()
        c, j = 0, 0
        for i in s1:
            if s2.find(i) >= 0 and j == s1.find(i):
                c += 1
            j += 1
        return f"matching percentage: {round(c/len(s1))}"
```

So far, I have written two programs(`routes.py` and `compare_input.html`) located inside the same folder. They look like this:

```
#routes.py

from flask import render_template

@app.route("/compare_input", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def compare_input():
    return render_template('compare_input.html')
```

```
#compare_input.html

<form action="action_to_perform_after_submission" method = "POST">
    <p>Input 1 <input type = "text" name = "Field1_name" /></p>
    <p>Input 2 <input type = "text" name = "Field2_name" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Also a screenshot of the product so far:
[image: run in localhost]

Being able to create input box, I got stuck. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action to the submit button that reads the values from the text boxes and passes them to your `compare_word_percentage()` method somehow.

Either it hits another API endpoint that runs this compare method and returns the result, or your frontend code simply runs that method and updates some element on the page to show the percent similarity.